# WHat would be an example of this function?

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

WHat would be an example of a Lebesgue integrable function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ satisfying:

> 1. $f$ is continuous.
> 2. $\limsup_{x\to \infty} f(x)=\infty$

Comment: Have you tried to find such example?

Comment: @DavidMitra How do i show that $f$ is Lebesgue-integrable? That is how do i show that $f\in L^1$?

Comment: @Tomás Yes.. but i have no idea..

Comment: Sorry, misread question.

Comment: Take a function whose graph consists of "spikes" centered at the positive integers whose  heights tend to $\infty$ such that  the lengths of their bases tend to $0$ sufficiently fast so that the sum of their areas is finite.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a continuous positive function $g$ with support $\subset [0,1]$, $\int_0^1g(x)dx<\infty$ and $g(1/2)=1$.

Then
$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty g(n^3x - n^4)\times n$ is good:

- $\int g(x)dx = \sum \int g(n^3x - n^4)dx \times n = \int_0^1g(x)dx \sum n^{-2}<\infty $
- $g(n^4 + 1/2n^3) = f(1/2)\times n = n$ hence $\limsup f = \infty$.